# "Value at index is null" error while using pandas_udf

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

For a DataFrame in pyspark, if a column is initialized with with F.lit(1) (or any other value), then it's assigned to some values inside pandas_udf (using shift() in this case, but can happen to any other functions), this causes the "Value at index is null" error.

Could anyone provide some hint at why does this happen? Is it a bug in pyspark?

See the code below and errors.

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(id=1, name='a', c=3),
Row(id=2, name='b', c=6),
Row(id=3, name='a', c=2),
Row(id=4, name='b', c=9),
Row(id=5, name='c', c=7)])

df = df.withColumn('f', F.lit(1))


@pandas_udf(df.schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def shift_test(pdf):
    pdf['f'] = pdf['c'].shift(1)
    return pdf

df = df.groupby(['name']).apply(shift_test)
df.show()
```

There's no such error if I set the column `f` equal to `c`
See the output below.

```
+---+---+----+---+
|  c| id|name|  f|
+---+---+----+---+
|  3|  1|   a|  1|
|  6|  2|   b|  1|
|  2|  3|   a|  1|
|  9|  4|   b|  1|
|  7|  5|   c|  1|
+---+---+----+---+


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-5b4a8c6e0258> in <module>
     18 
     19 df = df.groupby(['name']).apply(shift_test)
---> 20 df.show()

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o3378.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 97 in stage 426.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 97.3 in stage 426.0 (TID 6258, optoldevny1, executor 0): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Value at index is null
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.IntVector.get(IntVector.java:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.vectorized.ArrowColumnVector$IntAccessor.getInt(ArrowColumnVector.java:299)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.vectorized.ArrowColumnVector.getInt(ArrowColumnVector.java:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.vectorized.MutableColumnarRow.getInt(MutableColumnarRow.java:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1891)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1879)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1878)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2112)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2050)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:738)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3389)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3369)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2550)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2764)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor67.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Value at index is null
    at org.apache.arrow.vector.IntVector.get(IntVector.java:101)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.vectorized.ArrowColumnVector$IntAccessor.getInt(ArrowColumnVector.java:299)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.vectorized.ArrowColumnVector.getInt(ArrowColumnVector.java:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.vectorized.MutableColumnarRow.getInt(MutableColumnarRow.java:117)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage3.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$13$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:636)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:255)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$2.apply(SparkPlan.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:346)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:310)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Check my answer below

Comment: I had figured it out already. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like that pyspark can't handle missing values when it comes out of a pandas_udf. Before it enters into a pandas_udf, it expects certain data type for each column (as specified by the schema in 
`@pandas_udf(df.schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)`.

If there is any missing value (as can be generated by `shift` here), it throws out, as Java can't handle missing values (The exception is a Java excepption: `java.lang.IllegalStateException`).

To fix this, one needs to replace such missing values with values in proper type, here an `integer`.

This new `pandas_udf` function fixes the problem:

```
@pandas_udf(df.schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def shift_test(pdf):
    pdf['f'] = pdf['c'].shift(1)
    pdf['f'].fillna(value=-1, inplace=True) #replace missing values with -1
    return pdf
```

Here's the output

```
+---+---+----+---+
|  c| id|name|  f|
+---+---+----+---+
|  7|  5|   c| -1|
|  6|  2|   b| -1|
|  9|  4|   b|  6|
|  2|  3|   a| -1|
|  3|  1|   a|  2|
+---+---+----+---+
```

Answer (score 6):

The reason you are getting the error is because of the `null` value introduced by the `shift` function and secondly because you are not making any changes to the returned schema to accept the `null` values.

When you are giving the return schema as `df.schema`, spark by default is taking `nullable = False` from the original schema. So you need to provide a new schema here where for column `f`, where you need to set `nullable = True` to avoid this error.

```
# Schema of output DataFrame
new_schema = StructType([
    StructField("c", IntegerType(), False), 
    StructField("id", IntegerType(), False), 
    StructField("name", StringType(), False), 
    StructField("f", IntegerType(), True)
  ])

@pandas_udf(new_schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def shift_test(pdf):
    pdf['f'] = pdf['c'].shift(1)
    return pdf
```